# Binding multiple actions to the same event with Stimulus

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

Does anyone know if it's possible to bind multiple actions to the same event with Stimulus in a Rails template?

I currently have this:

```
<%= form.text_area :content, value: '', id: "message-input",
                           data: { action: "input->message-form#inputChange input->form#autogrowInput 
                           keydown.enter->message-form#sendMessage keydown.enter->message-actions#clearReply 
                           keydown.ctrl+enter->message-form#addNewLine keydown.ctrl+enter->form#autogrowInput", message_form_target: "messageInput", form_target: "inputField" },
                           class: "form-input-no-label", autofocus: true %>
```

I want to avoid duplicating the event calls and chain multiple actions like this:

```
<%= form.text_area :content, value: '', id: "message-input",
                           data: { action: "input->message-form#inputChange form#autogrowInput
                           keydown.enter->message-form#sendMessage message-actions#clearReply
                           keydown.ctrl+enter->message-form#addNewLine form#autogrowInput", message_form_target: "messageInput", form_target: "inputField" },
                           class: "form-input-no-label", autofocus: true %>
```

But this causes the actions named to stop working.

Does anyone know if it's possible to avoid event duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off just formatting your code:

```rb
<%= form.text_area :content,
  data: {
    action: %(
      input->message-form#inputChange
      input->form#autogrowInput
      keydown.enter->message-form#sendMessage
      keydown.enter->message-actions#clearReply
      keydown.ctrl+enter->message-form#addNewLine
      keydown.ctrl+enter->form#autogrowInput
    ),
    message_form_target: :messageInput,
    form_target: :inputField
  }
%>
```

This way you can quickly copy paste lines and move things around.

---

Alternatively, you could make a helper:

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def data_action hash
  hash.map do |event, actions|
    actions.map do |controller, action|
      "#{event}->#{controller.to_s.dasherize}##{action}"
    end
  end.join(" ")
end
```

```rb
<%= form.text_area :content,
  data: {
    action: data_action(
      input:                {message_form: :inputChange, form: :autogrowInput},
      "keydown.enter":      {message_form: :sendMessage, message_actions: :clearReply},
      "keydown.ctrl+enter": {message_form: :addNewLine,  form: :autogrowInput}
    ),
    message_form_target: :messageInput,
    form_target: :inputField
  }
%>
```

Comment: I like the helper idea, that's nice! Also yes, good call on reformatting. Thanks Alex!